# The second time when I login, there will shows `CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.`

Tags: javascript, csrf

The second time login （I mean after I login, I login again） will report :

```
{"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}
```

[image]

This is my request header:

```
POST /rest-auth/login/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.10.105:8001
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 41
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Authorization: Token 0fe2977498e51ed12ddc93026b08ab0b1a06a434
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.146 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: csrftoken=swTF9r03QikoOSpejwGQkmvYqb6PQfhXY4RBjowLQJCJNjKatpIY8EFTtGYyWEs4; sessionid=f0bxzo74wso48fyyyy6f6v8xqif1qunn
```

there is the Cookies:

[image]

If in the browser I clear the cookies then I login, there will has no error.

---

My login method is bellow:

```
    // 登录接口请求
    that.$http.post(Urls.users.login(), params).then((response) => {

      // 清除sessionid和csrftoken
      Cookies.remove('sessionid');
      Cookies.remove('csrftoken');

      setTimeout(loading, 0)
      that.$Message.success(Util.convert_error_data_to_str(response.statusText, response.data))
      that.$Cookies.set('token', response.data.key);

      that.get_user_info()

    }).catch((response) => {
        debugger
        setTimeout(loading, 0)
        this.$Message.error(Util.convert_error_data_to_str(response.statusText, response.data))
      }
    )
```

---

**EDIT-1**

I updated the key code, but still not work:

```
     var that = this

    // clear sessionid and csrftoken
    that.$Cookies.remove('sessionid');
    that.$Cookies.remove('csrftoken');

    // login
    that.$http.post(Urls.users.login(), params).then((response) => {

      setTimeout(loading, 0)

      that.$Cookies.set('token', response.data.key);

      that.get_user_info()

    }).catch((response) => {
        debugger
        setTimeout(loading, 0)

      }
    )
```

Seems the `this.$Cookies.remove('sessionid')`and `csrftoken` do not success:

[image]

Comment: Why are you removing sessionid and csrf from cookies

Comment: @moghya See my eidt-1.